# Is there any way to create a report on opportunity product? If yes please help me to create!

Tags: custom-report-type

I need to create a report on opportunity product so that i can show all opportunity product in status wise

Comment: You have standard OOB Opportunity product report type as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.reports_opps_with_products.htm&type=5), hope you can utilize it

Comment: @ShivankurNaikwade thank you

Answer (score 1):

View information about the products associated with your opportunities, including product name and opportunity stage using the OOB report type.

[Opportunities with Products Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.reports_opps_with_products.htm&type=5)